# Yii URL rewriting

Tags: php, url, yii

I want to rewrite my url in YII to make url seo friendly .
The URL in my current system is
 `http://mysite/recipe/recipedetail/1`

and i want to make it like

```
http://mysite/recipename
```

how i can do it

i am trying ot use rule but they are not working my rules in config/main files are

```
'url.rules' => array(
                      'recipe/<recipename:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>/' => 'recipe/recipedetail/<recipename:\w+>/',
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
'recipe/recipedetail/<id:\d+>'=>'recipe/recipedetail',
```

Answer (score 0):

A route part of rule must not contain parameters, but must be in `controller/action` format:

```
'url.rules' => array(
    'recipe/<recipename:[A-Za-z0-9-]+>/' => 'recipe/recipedetail',
),
```

All named parameters will be available in `$_GET`, so inside your controller action you can access `recipename` value with `$_GET['recipename`]`.

Additionaly, please mention that you must not wrap parameter pattern (`[A-Za-z0-9-]+` in your case) in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing var_name in your url

```
'recipe/<recipename:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>/' => 'recipe/recipedetail/var_name/<recipename:\w+>/'
```

get the recipename inside your controller using var_name